# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named: openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed opencv for example, and when importing in sublimetext or in a terminal I jump "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named". If I do it from the python idle, it does not

Comment: sublimetext is using a different python.

Comment: He says he has the same error when he is trying to import in the terminal. So obviously this does nothing have to do with sublimetext.

Comment: @LeonardCapacete So I must rephrase it. You installed cvpython for some python, but you are using a different python in sublimetext and the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your error and was able to fix it as following:

This error often happens when you did not added your Python path correctly.

To check wether your python is installed an configured correctly go to your terminal and type:

```
python -V
```

and then:

```
pip -v
```

The two versions have to match.

Also simply run:

```
python
```

and check wether an interactive shell opens.
If your versions are matching and the the `python` command works, your python is configured correctly and you can skip the next step. If not follow the steps below, if everthing works skip this:

For Windows try this:
https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path

For Mac OS try this:

```
export PATH=~/path/to/your/python/bin:$PATH
```

For example:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

Now the next thing...

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Now you are ready to go an you can import opencv in your code as following:

```
import cv2
```

When you are using pyhton3 use:

```
python3 test.py
```

to run your code.

If you want to use `python` instead of `python3` do this:

The last Python you install that registers itself in the environment is the default.

If you would like to have Python 3.x as a default version, then you will need to create environment variable 'PY_PYTHON' and set it's value to 3

Comment: `pip` is also capable of resolving dependencies, so there's absolutely not need to explicitly install those "prerequisites".