# Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError.. No module named 'cv2'

Tags: windows, opencv, modulenotfounderror

I have installed opencv in windows laptop.
and tried to run this code below

```py
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('pictures/dog.jpg')
cv.imshow('dog',img)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

and it gives error like this

> Exception has occurred:ModuleNOtFoundError
> No module named 'cv2'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named: openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50416424/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

You must install the package by using the pip package manager:

```
pip install opencv-python
```